# email message with Object__c.Id is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce page, and a controller class. the object name is Calculator__c. I have a method which sends an email out with the data. and the send email method is called after save() method.
on one line, I have

```
mail.setSubject('Calculator -- Manager Approval Request ' + Calculator__c.Id);
```

I set the email send to myself, and when I got it, the email Subject only says:
 "Calculator -- Manager Approval Request Id", the actual Id number was not sent. can someone help, thanks so much.

Comment: Can you post the controller code and visualforce?  My guess is you're simply instantiating a new Calculator__c object and never retrieving it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculator__c.Id is a field reference (Schema.Calculator__c.Id). You need to reference an instance of the record (say, from your ApexPages.StandardController controller parameter), such as `controller.getRecord().Id` or `controller.getId()`.

**Edit**: I should note that if you're using an extension, you want to save the StandardController that the constructor provides. If you're using a controller, you have to create an instance of the record yourself as a member variable, such as:

```
public class X {
    public Calculator__c calc { get; set; }
    public X() {
        calc = new Calculator__c(); // Or do a query, etc.
    }
}
```

At which point, you'd want to refer to `calc.Id` (assuming you've inserted or queried first).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change it to reference the actual record's Id. Calculator__c.Id will retrieve information about that field on the object model instead of the value of the record.